# Nilpotents of order 2 are dense in the strong operator topology

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I need some help with this homework problem. (The Hilbert space in question is $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.)

I let $T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ and looked at a basic nbhd in the strong operator topology (SOT) generated by the points $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Without loss of generality, assume the points are orthonormal.

Let $\mathcal{W} := \mathrm{span}\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and let $\mathcal{V}$ be the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{W}$.

What I wanted to do was define an operator $N : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ by $N(\mathcal{W})=0$ and $N(x_i) = y_i$, where $y_i \in B_{\epsilon}(Tx_i)\cap\mathcal{V}$.

Then it's pretty easy to show that $N$ is nilpotent of order 2 and lies in the basic nbhd of $T$. However, I'm having trouble justifying the existence of such a $y_i \in B_{\epsilon}(Tx_i)\cap\mathcal{V}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason for such $y_i$'s to exist at all; $T$ is arbitrary. Try taking $x_i$ to $Tx_i$ and $Tx_i$ to $0$.

Comment: But you can't define the map on its action on the set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ that way if $T(x_i) \in \mathcal{W}$ for some $x_i$.